# How to populate an array with HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i want to make a content slider. I have 8 LI elements and want to make an array with those elements. So far i have done that by adding a unique ID or Name to each of them and making a variable with that element, but i believe that there is a better way of doing this, i just dont know it because i am a designer, not a developer. 
Code:
In HTML

```
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/c++.png" />
                <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>

                <h3>John Purcell</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />
                <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />
                <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />
                <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/c++.png" />
                <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>

                <h3>John Purcell</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />
                <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />
                <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />
                <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Give each of your li elements a shared class name like class="myLiShared", then you can use document.getElementsByClassName("myLiShared") to return an htmlcollection of your li elements. which you can then iterate over and manipulate how you see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of your elements which is similar to an array by using `querySelectorAll`. If you were to add a class such as `list` to your ul, you could get them like this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.list li')
```

A NodeList can do some things an array can do. If you need to change it to an array like this:

```
var itemsArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".list li"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the shared class to each li element like below:

```
  <ul>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/c++.png" />
            <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>

            <h3>John Purcell</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />
            <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>

            <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />
            <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>

            <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />
            <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>

            <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/c++.png" />
            <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>

            <h3>John Purcell</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />
            <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>

            <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />
            <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>

            <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="myLiShared">
            <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />
            <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>

            <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Then in your javascript code you can get the li elements as an htmlcollection like so:

```
let myCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("myLiShared");
//Now you can iterate over your li elements like so
for(let x = 0; x < myCollection.length; x++){
     //Do something with your li element
     //myCollection[x]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends the surrounding code. You can just add a class to each li and use `$('.className').toArray();` or if this is your only list, you could even use `$('li').toArray();`.

For vanilla javascript, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.className');` or `document.querySelectorAll('li');`

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery alternative

- Apply a class to your `ul` element and execute this selector `.classname li`.
- To populate those elements into an array, call the native jQuery function `toArray()`

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var array = $('.list li').toArray();
console.log(array);
```

```css
.list {
  display: none
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script><ul class='list'>  <li>    <img src="../images2/c++.png" />    <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>    <h3>John Purcell</h3>  </li>  <li>    <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />    <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>    <h3>Derek Banas</h3>  </li>  <li>    <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />    <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>    <h3>Derek Banas</h3>  </li>  <li>    <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />    <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>    <h3>Derek Banas</h3>  </li>  <li>    <img src="../images2/c++.png" />    <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>    <h3>John Purcell</h3>  </li>  <li>    <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />    <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>    <h3>Derek Banas</h3>  </li>  <li>    <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />    <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>    <h3>Derek Banas</h3>  </li>  <li>    <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />    <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>    <h3>Derek Banas</h3>  </li></ul>
```

See? the `li` elements were populated into an array.

## Resource

- [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)